# How to escape only quotes in haproxy log format

Tags: haproxy, json

I am capturing the `user-agent` using:

```
http-request capture req.hdr(User-Agent) len 192
```

And then trying to create a custom `JSON` log format like this:

```
log-format '{"User-Agent":%{+Q,+E}[capture.req.hdr(0)]}'
```

It works but when a User Agent includes square brackets, for example:

```
Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.4; Ixion X LTE 4.5 [Build KTU84P])
```

The option `+E` escapes the square bracket and brakes the JSON, it creates something like:

```
"User-Agent": "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.4; Ixion X LTE 4.5 \[Build KTU84P])"
```

When the UA contains extra quotes there is no problem:

```
"User-Agent": "this \"works\" fine"
```

Therefore wondering if there is a way to specify escaping only double quotes or alternatives to make the log format `JSON` compatible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer version of haproxy have a built-in json encoder, which you can use to define a JSON log format. See https://www.haproxy.org/download/2.1/doc/configuration.txt

> `json([<input-code>])`
>     Escapes the input string and produces an ASCII output string ready to use as a
>     JSON string. The converter tries to decode the input string according to the
>     `<input-code>` parameter. It can be "`ascii`", "`utf8`", "`utf8s`", "`utf8p`" or
>     "utf8ps". The "ascii" decoder never fails.
>    ....
>     Example:
>
> ```
> capture request header Host len 15
> capture request header user-agent len 150
> log-format '{"ip":"%[src]","user-agent":"%[capture.req.hdr(1),json(utf8s)]"}'
> ```
>
> Input request from client 127.0.0.1:
>
> ```
> GET / HTTP/1.0
>
> User-Agent: Very "Ugly" UA 1/2
> ```
>
> Output log:
>
> ```
> {"ip":"127.0.0.1","user-agent":"Very \"Ugly\" UA 1\/2"}
> ```

Comment: Just in case also working in versions `2.0.X`